# Oracle SQL time difference in HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I am trying to get time difference in Oracle database. The time difference for all the rows is okay except for one row. Here is the query

```
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR (CAST(TO_DATE(call_end, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(TO_DATE(call_start, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')) AS call_time
FROM calls
```

The time difference occurs with the following row:

call_end: '2020-02-20 13:00:20'
call_start: '2020-02-20 12:56:03'

The returned result is '11:55:43' which is wrong. As the correct answer should be '00:04:17'

Comment: i think there is an additional row causing this issue,can you remove the MAX and try to run the query and see if it fetches two rows.

Comment: Why do you think it's that row that's causing the issue? Is there a a unique key you can filter on to be sure you're only getting that row and that result for it? Also why are you storing the call start/end time as strings? (If you are - maybe they are already dates, and you're doing an implicit conversion - what are your NLS date/timestamp format settings, and does your client override them?)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your table already stores the call start/end times as dates, and you're doing an implicit conversion from date to string, then converting back to a date. You can see that result if you have HH instead of HH24 in your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS';

with calls (call_end, call_start) as (
  select cast(timestamp '2020-02-20 13:00:20' as date), cast(timestamp '2020-02-20 12:56:03' as date) from dual
)
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR (CAST(TO_DATE(call_end, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(TO_DATE(call_start, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')) AS call_time
FROM calls;

CALL_TIME                  
---------------------------
11:55:43
```

When you do

```
TO_DATE(call_end, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

because it's already a date you're really doing:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(call_end, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

so with my setting (and yours must be similar, maybe with slashes instead of dashes) that is:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(call_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

and the mismatch between HH and HH24 becomes more obvious. So, you're actually converting the strings 2020-02-20 01:00:20 and 2020-02-20 12:56:03 back to dates, and the time difference between 01:00:20 and 12:56:03 is 11:55:43. Well - actually, it is *minus* 11 hours:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DATE(call_end, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(TO_DATE(call_start, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM calls;

CAST(TO_DATE(CALL_E
-------------------
-00 11:55:43.000000
```

but your regex isn't picking that up.

As they are dates skip that part of the conversion completely, and just cast directly to timestamps if you want intervals to work from:

```
SELECT MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR (CAST(call_end AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(call_start AS TIMESTAMP), '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')) AS call_time
FROM calls;

CALL_TIME                  
---------------------------
00:04:17
```

or use a substring instead of a regex, as @MTO showed.

You could also leave them as dates, get the difference as a fraction of a day, add that back to any nominal date at midnight, and then convert the resulting date to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '2000-01-01' + MAX(call_end - call_start), 'HH24:MI:SS') AS call_time
FROM calls;

CALL_TIM
--------
00:04:17
```

This won't work properly for a call that lasts more than 24 hours (used to see that a lot with modem calls, but can still happen); but neither will your interval approach. Both ignore any full days and just show the remainder. There are ways to handle that of course, but you'd need to decide how you want to display it - with separate day count (like interval does anyway), or with the 'hours' number allowed to go above 24... but then you may go above 99 hours...

---

Your question shows the call end time as 2020-02-20 13:00:20, which suggests that's how your client is displaying it when you query the table. Some clients (I think PL/SQL Developer, but not sure, it's been a while) use their own preferences/settings instead of honouring the session's NLS settings. But that has no effect on how Oracle behaves internally when it has to do implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want the result as an interval or timestamp, but this should do what you want:

```
select t.*, call_end - call_start,
       substr(to_char(call_end - call_start, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 8) as str    from (select timestamp '2020-02-20 13:00:20.000' as call_end,
             timestamp '2020-02-20 12:56:03.000' as call_start
      from dual) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08d049391863b5007e756c16f6aac879) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data types are strings (you really should store them as `DATE` data types), you can use:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         MAX(
           ( TO_DATE( call_end,   'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
           - TO_DATE( call_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
           ) DAY(1) TO SECOND
         ),
         4,
         8
       ) AS call_time
FROM   calls
```

If they are already `DATE` data types then, in the `MAX` aggregation, just use:

```sql
( call_end - call_start ) DAY(1) TO SECOND
```

So for your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE calls ( call_end, call_start ) AS
SELECT '2020-02-20 13:00:20', '2020-02-20 12:56:03' FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | CALL_TIME |
> | :-------- |
> | 00:04:17  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1da05ac53ccdea8cadc16aa3ffabab98)*

Answer (score 0):

Mr Gyl, You can as well do: [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7eee1385c20346cee2af8a7c61b24859) :This solution will also consider when the call has lapsed over days by adding those hours together:

```
WITH da AS (
SELECT
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_DATE('2020-02-20 13:00:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - TO_DATE('2020-02-20 12:56:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'DAY') AS call_diff
FROM
    dual ) SELECT
    EXTRACT( DAY FROM call_diff )*24 + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM call_diff )|| ':' || EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM call_diff ) || ':' || EXTRACT( SECOND FROM call_diff ) DIFFERENCE
FROM
    da
```

> ```
> DIFFERENCE|
> ----------|
> 0:4:17    |
> ```

So you can implement as

```
WITH da AS (    
SELECT
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_DATE(call_end, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - TO_DATE(call_start, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'DAY') AS call_diff
FROM
    calls
    ) SELECT
    EXTRACT( DAY FROM call_diff )*24 + EXTRACT( HOUR FROM call_diff )|| ':' || EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM call_diff ) || ':' || EXTRACT( SECOND FROM call_diff ) TIMESTAMP
FROM
    da
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below response but this will only work within 24hrs and returns both '00'

```
WITH sample_lt AS(
                            SELECT '2020-02-20 12:56:03' START_TIME, '2020-02-20 13:00:20' END_TIME FROM dual
                                 )
                    SELECT start_time,
                            end_time,
                                TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (to_date(end_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') -
                                  to_date(start_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
                                 ) , 'hh24:mi:ss' ) duration
                    FROM sample_lt ;
```